# pyqt load graphiicspixmapitem on demand

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to load a series of images at a certain position in a pyqt scene. The number of images could go up in hundreds or thousands. When I run it, it takes a long time to load the gui.

I would like to load the picture thats visible in the graphicsView and then delay loading the other images until its in the viewport.

Could someone please tell me how to approach this?

```
class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyView, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setViewportUpdateMode(self.smartViewportUpdate)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        path = '/path/'
        for i in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
            file = os.path.join(path, f)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(file)
            pix_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
            pix_item.setPos(i*250, 0)
            self.scene.addItem(pix_item)
```

Comment: Do you have the preset positions?

Comment: Ultimately yes. These images would be placed in the scene first, perhaps in a grid like format. Users would then move them around to group them as they see fit. When they open it again, I would reload their positions.